# Postman: Get bearer token from collection authorization in pre-request script

Tags: authentication, http-headers, postman, postman-pre-request-script

In postman I have a collection, where each request uses collection-level Bearer Token authorization.

[image: Collection Authorization]

Now, what I would like to do is to send http request in my pre-request script (For refreshing access token), but I don't know is it possible to get access token (from collection Authorization) in pre-request scripts. I know I can get collection variables like

`pm.collectionVariables.get("key)`,

but is there also a way to get (and also set)
value from Authorization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Token as a collection variable `{{my_token}}` and then use
`pm.collectionVariables.set("my_token", "tokenvaluehere")` in your pre-request script.

[image]

Comment: How do we automatically handle the case when token is expired ?

Comment: @insanely_sin You can handle the response in the Test script. Tests execute after the request is completed. See - https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/test-scripts/